# Can I set specific env variable to only one of the Pods within a deployment with multiple replicas?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a deployment of my backend app which has 6 replicas. In the code of the app, I have a node.js cronjob running every minute. But the problem is that because I have 6 replicas, it runs 6 times in parallel. I want to send env variable to exactly only one Pod in the deployment to ensure that only 1 Pod performs the cronjob. Then in the app code I will check this using the `process.env.SHOULD_PROCESS_CRONJOBS == 1`.

If this is not the right way to achieve what I need, can you inform me on how to handle cronjobs using nodejs in distributed environment like K8S?

Comment: Are you using regular cron in the pod? or some form of node scheduler? k8s has the ability to schedule a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) outside of your application pods.

Comment: The cronjob itself should be run separately outside of the app in its own container / job instance. Look into decoupling your cron logic from your application so that it can run independently on its own as a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

Comment: If node.js is doing the scheduling, The jobs container template would be largely the same as the applications. Just change the `command` to the short lived task, instead of the long lived application.

Comment: The k8s is doing the scheduling. So basically you say that I need to change the code - removing the cronjob from the app and create another app just for this cronjob that will be run using the k8s cronjob resource?

Comment: Raz Buchnik, @Matt and maiorano84 proposed to schedule a job in k8s using a CronJob (a built-in feature of Kubernetes). It is the best way to schedule jobs in Kubernetes. Do you think the proposed CronJob is an acceptable answer to your initial question?

Answer (score 1):

Let Kubernetes schedule a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) in addition to the application

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: app-cron
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-app-cron
            image: same-as-app
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from scheduled job
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

If you don't want kubernetes supervising the cron scheduling, then another option is to split out the application that schedules the cron into two Deployments. Only use 1 replica for the container that has environment variable:

```
      env:
      - name: SHOULD_PROCESS_CRONJOBS
        value: "1"
```